# Bucket Sort/Counting Sort of Large File

Tags: python, linux, sorting, gnu, large-files

I have a very large file I want to sort through (10s of TB) in a coarse manner. Basically, I hash one of the fields in this file, take the last 4 digits of that hash and append it as a column. This gives me a 4 digit base16 number associated with each line, which means each line can fit into one of 65536 buckets. I want to then distribute this file between 65536 files, each representing one of these buckets.

I don't think GNU sort is smart enough to speed this operation up- I can't specify that there are only 65536 possible keys, so my assumption is that it will approach this like it would any other sort operation.

My current strategy is to open 65536 file handles and go through the file line-by line, writing each line to the appropriate file. This breaks ulimit bounds for a single user, which I know can be modified, but I'm unsure if this is a good strategy. Has anyone done something like this before?

Right now I have a python script that looks like this:

```python
bucketfilemap = { ... } # 65536 open files
s = time.time()
with open(infile, 'rb') as inf:
    for line in inf:
        tokens = line.split(delim)
        bucketkey = tokens[keyloc]
        bucketfilemap[bucketkey].write(line)
e = time.time()
print("time total:", (e - s))
```

In my testing on smaller files, it has been slower than I'd like, though it does scale linearly with the size of the file, which is what I would like.

Comment: Here's an alternative to consider.  Start 256 subprocesses.  Your main loop funnels each line to a listener, based on the high-order byte.  The subprocesses then shuffle into 256 files each, based on the low-order byte.  That won't be faster, but it gets around the ulimit problems.

Comment: I commented out the writing part and only got 100MB/s over a 600MB input file (compared to 1700MB/s of `wc -l`). I would definitely choose a faster language for this. Also check what backs your storage to see whether you should parallelize. Raising the FD limit for this is fine, though I doubt you'd lose a lot of performance from simply caching up a handful of GB in memory and appending to the files in a loop.

Comment: @"that other guy" Yeah I think I will try writing this in C and C (haha) where that gets me. I'll consider that caching suggestion. With the writing part added I achieve rather abysmal speeds (~2MB/s) compared to the theoretical output of my testing disk while writing (~188MB/s)

Comment: The last time I had to sort huge amounts of data I coded my own merge sort in C++. It worked great.

Comment: @BenT you have to remove spaces from user names when addressing a user in comments and do not use quotes ... for example `@thatotherguy`

Comment: @jsotola oh, weird. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I designed a C program to do this in place of the python script. Made an odd discovery, but ultimately it is much faster.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define N 65536
#define N2 4

// custom hex to integer
int hextoint(char* str) {

        int t = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N2; i++) {
                char c = str[i];
                if (c < 58) {
                        t |= ((int)(c-48))<<(i<<2); // each hex digits represents 4 bits, 16=2**4
                } else {
                        t |= ((int)(c-87))<<(i<<2);
                }
        }
        return t;

}

int bucketsort(char* infilename, char** outfilenames) {

        FILE* buckets[N];
        FILE* infile;
        char lbuf[512];
        int hashidx;
        int cp;
        int len;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                buckets[i] = fopen(outfilenames[i], "wb");
        }

        infile = fopen(infilename, "rb");

        int j = 0;
        while (1) {
                cp = fgets(lbuf, sizeof(lbuf), infile);
                if (cp == NULL) {
                        break;
                }
                len = strlen(lbuf);
                hashidx = hextoint(lbuf); // file should be formatted such that the hex key always comes at the beginning of the line
                fwrite(lbuf, 1, len, buckets[hashidx]);
                j++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                int r = fclose(buckets[i]);
        }


        return 0;
}

void main(int argc, char** argv) {

        char* outfilesfilename = argv[2];
        char* infilename = argv[1];
        FILE* outfilefd = fopen(outfilesfilename, "r");
        char lbuf[512];
        char** outfilenames = malloc(sizeof(char*)*N);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                outfilenames[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
        }

        int i = 0;
        while (fgets(lbuf, sizeof(lbuf), outfilefd)) {
                int len = strlen(lbuf);
                memcpy(outfilenames[i], lbuf, len-1);
                i++;
        }

        bucketsort(infilename, outfilenames);

}
```

The odd discovery I made is that `fclose` can be very slow in C, and that speed seems to depend on the number of file descriptors open. Opening the files is quick, and writing to them also quick. However, when I have 65536 files open, performing 65536 fcloses takes 30-50 seconds. When I change N to 256 (and N2 to 2) it takes barely a tenth of a second.

```
640MB file
N = 256
1.970000 seconds elapsed on write
0.110000 seconds elapsed on close

N = 65536
4.550000 seconds elapsed on write
36.869999 seconds elapsed on close
```

It does not matter if I'm writing 500KB or 640MB, it always takes 30-50 seconds to close the files, whereas it would take python ~0.24 seconds to write out 500KB to 65536 files. This is still better, as it seems to be sort of a constant cost rather than one that scales with the size of the file. For example, with the 500KB file:

```
500KB file
0.440000 seconds elapsed on write
45.889999 seconds elapsed on close
```